# textview not updating (shoutcast stream metadata in android 2.2)

Tags: android, textview, metadata, shoutcast

i have a IcyStreamMeta.class that gets the metadata info of shoutcast Stream i use the method below to update the textview in my main activity and display the current song title playing. the code below works on android 2.1 and android 1.5 somehow it doesnt work on android 2.2 i dont know whats wrong i cant figure it out. i need you help guys :)

**here is my IcyStreamMeta class**

```
public class IcyStreamMeta<Message> {

protected URL streamUrl;
private Map<String, String> metadata;
private boolean isError;

public IcyStreamMeta(URL streamUrl) {
    setStreamUrl(streamUrl);

    isError = false;
}

/**
 * Get artist using stream's title
 *
 * @return String
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String getArtist() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

    if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
        return "";

    String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
    String title = streamTitle.substring(0, streamTitle.indexOf("-"));
    return title.trim();
}

/**
 * Get title using stream's title
 *
 * @return String
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String getTitle() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

    if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
        return "";

    String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
    String artist = streamTitle.substring(streamTitle.indexOf("-")+1);
    return artist.trim();
}

public Map<String, String> getMetadata() throws IOException {
    if (metadata == null) {
        refreshMeta();
    }

    return metadata;
}

public void refreshMeta() throws IOException {
    retreiveMetadata();
}

private void retreiveMetadata() throws IOException {
    URLConnection con = streamUrl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Icy-MetaData", "1");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", null);
    con.connect();

    int metaDataOffset = 0;
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = con.getHeaderFields();
    InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();

    if (headers.containsKey("icy-metaint")) {
        // Headers are sent via HTTP
        metaDataOffset = Integer.parseInt(headers.get("icy-metaint").get(0));
    } else {
        // Headers are sent within a stream
        StringBuilder strHeaders = new StringBuilder();
        char c;
        while ((c = (char)stream.read()) != -1) {
            strHeaders.append(c);
            if (strHeaders.length() > 5 && (strHeaders.substring((strHeaders.length() - 4), strHeaders.length()).equals("\r\n\r\n"))) {
                // end of headers
                break;
            }
        }

        // Match headers to get metadata offset within a stream
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\r\\n(icy-metaint):\\s*(.*)\\r\\n");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(strHeaders.toString());
        if (m.find()) {
            metaDataOffset = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        }
    }

    // In case no data was sent
    if (metaDataOffset == 0) {
        isError = true;
        return;
    }

    // Read metadata
    int b;
    int count = 0;
    int metaDataLength = 4080; // 4080 is the max length
    boolean inData = false;
    StringBuilder metaData = new StringBuilder();
    // Stream position should be either at the beginning or right after headers
    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
        count++;

        // Length of the metadata
        if (count == metaDataOffset + 1) {
            metaDataLength = b * 16;
        }

        if (count > metaDataOffset + 1 && count < (metaDataOffset + metaDataLength)) {              
            inData = true;
        } else {                
            inData = false;             
        }               
        if (inData) {               
            if (b != 0) {                   
                metaData.append((char)b);               
            }           
        }               
        if (count > (metaDataOffset + metaDataLength)) {
            break;
        }

    }

    // Set the data
    metadata = IcyStreamMeta.parseMetadata(metaData.toString());

    // Close
    stream.close();
}

public boolean isError() {
    return isError;
}

public URL getStreamUrl() {
    return streamUrl;
}

public void setStreamUrl(URL streamUrl) {
    this.metadata = null;
    this.streamUrl = streamUrl;
    this.isError = false;
}

public static Map<String, String> parseMetadata(String metaString) {
    Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap();
    String[] metaParts = metaString.split(";");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\\'([^\\']*)\\'$");
    Matcher m;
    for (int i = 0; i < metaParts.length; i++) {
        m = p.matcher(metaParts[i]);
        if (m.find()) {
            metadata.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
        }
    }

    return metadata;
}   
    }
```

here is the method i use in my MAIN ACTIVITY to display the song title in my textview

```
private void getmeta()
{
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run(){

    URL url;
    try{
        url = new URL("http://www.rakista.com:8000/listen.mp3");
        IcyStreamMeta icy = new IcyStreamMeta(url);
        A = icy.getArtist();
        Artist.setText(A);

    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
},0,2000);

    //Log.i("Artist: ", A);
}
```

**Update:**

**my main Activty**

```
private class 

public class RakistaRadio extends Activity
{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
Artist =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ARTIST);

}
}
```

Comment: Please show me the line were you set a string to a TextView. Is it this: `Artist.setText(A);`? What class is `Artist`, where did you declare it?

Comment: it is declared on top of my oncreate().......... private TextView Artist; public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
  Artist =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ARTIST);

Comment: First of all you should follow the programming standard which says variable names start with lower case letters and classes start with uppercase. It's because of the better readability. Do you get any errors or warnings at Android 2.2 or when you call `Artist.setText(A)`? I guess you get an exception and can't see it because you used `e.printStackTrace()` to show it. Use `Artis.setText(e.toString())` instead or if you have LogCat simply `Log.v("IcyStreamMeta", e.toString())` to make it visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit late, but I was looking for the same answer as you and with a little re-factoring, I got your code to work. I hope this helps!

```
/**
 * Get Meta Data From SHOUTcast
 */
private void getMeta()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                IcyStreamMeta icy   = new IcyStreamMeta(new URL("http://www.rakista.com:8000"));
                data                = icy.getArtist() + " - " + icy.getTitle();
                meta                = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meta);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                     public void run()
                     {
                         meta.setText(data);
                     }
                });
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },0,5000);
}
```

Note that the variables `data` and `meta` are defined in the class root, not any method.